# getting an error while creating react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

hello public Am getting an error while creating an react application don't know what's going on wrong please try to fix my error

and also tell me what should i do?

> note :: my internet connection is good

my updated latest node and other packages https://ibb.co/tmyyB4M

```
F:\React JS>npx create-react-app project

Creating a new React app in F:\React JS\project.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.10
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "F:\\React JS\\project\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd F:\React JS\project has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens in case your internet connection is too slow, one way of fixing it if your are using Yarn is by increasing Yarn network timeout,

Refrence : https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4890#issuecomment-358179301

Comment: there is no problem in internet connection my internet connection is more tan 5 mbps

Answer (score 0):

Do The following!

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm uninstall -g yarn
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app your-project-name
```